# How do I find out what is the first visible item (string) in a SWT List

Tags: swt

I have a List in my dialog and I want to find out what it the first visible String in the list where ever the list is scrolled at that moment. Is there a way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

List.getTopIndex() should be helpful in identifying the index of the top visible element. After the index is obtained, getItem (index) can be used to obtain the string value.

So, the API should be list.getItem (getTopIndex())